# text positioning for select list

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have following issue, I have hierarchy table where every record has level, code and description and I need to have description to look as it is was one column.

Example code

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Value NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #tmp (Value) VALUES ('L1 [ABC]'),('    L2 [DEFGH]'),('        L3 [E]')

SELECT 
Value + SPACE(50 - DATALENGTH(Value)) + 'Description text'
FROM #tmp
```

Output

[image]

But i need to have description to start at red line for every hierarchy record.
Any idea ?

Comment: You need to use a fixed-width font, such as Courier.

Comment: You should not be formatting like this in SSMS. Format in your presentation layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [len()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/SV-SE/library/ms190329.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of [datalength()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) to get the number of characters in `Value`. They are different because `Value` is a double byte string (nvarchar).

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Value NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #tmp (Value) VALUES ('L1 [ABC]'),('    L2 [DEFGH]'),('        L3 [E]')

SELECT 
Value + SPACE(50 - DATALENGTH(Value)) + 'Description text'
FROM #tmp

SELECT 
Value + SPACE(50 - LEN(Value)) + 'Description text'
FROM #tmp
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
L1 [ABC]                                  Description text
    L2 [DEFGH]                      Description text
        L3 [E]                      Description text

(3 row(s) affected)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------
L1 [ABC]                                          Description text
    L2 [DEFGH]                                    Description text
        L3 [E]                                    Description text
```

Comment: It works, I did not used LEN because it does not count trailing spaces for example SELECT LEN(' abc d '), DATALENGTH(' abc d ') but I wasn't aware of other differencies.

Comment: @Muflix Remove trailing space with `RTRIM`. `SELECT RTRIM(Value) + SPACE(50 - LEN(Value)) + 'Description text'`

Answer (score 0):

Max Vernon: you were right, Courier did the trick.

I added `style:"font-family: Courier New"` to the `<selected>` tag.